# Webservice Testing using soapUI Assertions

Tags: web-services, soapui

I would like to test the response of some webservice with soapUI assertions. For the following json response:

```
 "car":    {
      "id": 42,
      "carColor": "red"
      "carType": "BMW"
}
```

, how can I test, that..

1. car `ids` have always the type `integer` and `carColor` and `carType` have always the type `string`
2. the datas `id, carColor` and `carType` always exist for all cars

with soapUI assertions?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience SoapUI is not very good at this as is.  If you are comfortable using groovy scripts, then I'd recommend adding the JSONPath jar to your bin\ext directory and using it inside the groovy scripts.

[JSON Path](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

JSONPath is a lot like XPath.

If you are already comfortable with XPath, you can [convert JSON to XML](https://discursive.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CJCOOK/Converting+JSON+to+XML) and then use Xpath.

If you don't want to use groovy scripts, I am afraid I don't have any ideas....

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look on this post:
http://www.robert-nemet.com/2012/08/json-asserting-in-soapui.html
explaining possible way of JSON assertion in SoapUI